# Editable web data grid for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

A customer asked me for a web app, written in ASP.NET, that can use an editable grid (that works with a SqlServer DB) in a similar manner as Excel works. I can use `gridView` with Edit link in every row but I wanted to know if there are better solutions (possibly free) that I can use.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

We have recently started using the [ASPxGridView from Devexpress.](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Grid/)   It seems very good, especially for large datasets.

It is not like Excel, as such, but it does allow add/edit/delete from within the control and supports SQL Server.